# How to extract values between specific sequence in java

Tags: java, byte, bufferedreader

This is the [FILE](http://pastebin.com/wPyVP8ib) I am reading 
How to get a specific value from this file.

I want to get data

> Starting form 2000 to 466 character , starting from 4000 to 550(It can
>   be there or ellse it will be empty) and data from 6000 to 328
>   characters.

ie

```
Line 1 : Starts from character 2000 to 466 characters
Line 2 : starts from character 4000 to 550 characters
Line 3 : starts from character 4000 to 550 characters
Line 4 : starts from character 6000 to 328 characters
```

And ignore the remaining part mainly the file header and file footer.

What I did so far is

**UPDATE**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
newSize = in.readLine(buffer);
System.out.println("newsize-------------"+newSize);
while (newSize > 0) {
 String str = buffer.toString();
 sb.append(str);
 sb.append("\n");
 newSize = in.readLine(buffer);
}
String s = sb.toString();
/*
 * differentiating header,body and footer
 */
if(s.length() >0){

 String header = sb.toString().substring(0,466);
 System.out.println("header-------------------"+header);

 //unable to get body part
}
```

How to get the body part?

Comment: downvoters please comment .so  I can improve my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by:

- Read the whole content of the file in a String variable.
- call `substring` method for your specific char index

**Note:** you have to check the string variable length before calling `substring` method to avoid the out of bound exception.

**UPDATE**

If i were you, ill not use a fixed value to get sub string value, but ill use `indexOf` method to determine the index that i should sub my string.

**For Example:**

```
int startIndex= fileContent.indexOf("some unique starting characters");
int endIndex = fileContent.indexOf("some unique endingcharacters");
```

Comment: Yes Salah I am able to process the header part.But displaying empty for body part-ie starting from character "4000" to 550 bytes.But when I looked into the file from 4000 it starts showing 1 to 550.The file is like line 1 header - 0-466, Line 2 body - 0 -550 and Line 3 footer - 0-328

Comment: Filecontent only contains unique start index no end.U can verify in the input.But it can be like FileContentcontains(2000) then get data till 466 character ,if contains(4000) get data till 550 [this can be zero or more] and if contains (6000) get data till 328. And 2000 and 6000 are headers

Comment: So, i think you got the solution for your problem.